# Prove that $a^n - b^n$ does not divide $a^n + b^n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility

> Prove that $$a^n - b^n \text{ does not divide } a^n + b^n \text { and } a,b,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+. n > 1$$

I have tried to prove this but have had no success. My efforts till now were concerned with showing that $a-b \mid a^n-b^n$ while it does not divide $a^n+b^n$.

I would prefer a number theoretic answer. Thanks.

Source: Introduction to Theory of Numbers

Comment: Under what conditions? It's not true if $b=0$, for example.

Comment: It will divide if  b equals 0.  Consider if $a^n - b^n|a^n + b^n$ then $a^n - b^n| (a^n + b^n) - (a^n - b^n)= 2a^n$.

Comment: Even given $b>0$, this will not be true. Take $a=2$, $b=1$, $n=1$ gives $a^n-b^n=1$ which divides $a^n+b^n=3$.

Comment: @fleablood The numbers are **strictly** positive.

Comment: Then say so in the op.

Comment: for the condition to be true a and b  be relatively prime unless a = 1 or 2.  Can we assume a^n - b^n > 0?  a not equal b?

Comment: @fleablood Why does a have to be 1 or 2 to make them relatively prime?

Comment: @Dhruv $a$ does not necessarily need to be $1$ or $2$ in order to make them relatively prime.  He is saying that when $a$ is $1$ or $2$ that bad things happen.  Two numbers $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime iff $\gcd(a,b)=1$.  For example $20$ and $17$ are relatively prime.

Comment: @JMoravitz What are 'bad things'?

Comment: See my first comment.  $a^n - b^n|a^n + b^n \implies a^n - b^n|2b^n$ and $a^n - b^n|b^n$.  If $p|a$ then $p|2b$ and they can not be relatively prime for the condition to hold unless a = 2 and b=1 but then n = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the answers in [Why does $a^n - b^n$ never divide $a^n + b^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71779/why-does-an-bn-never-divide-an-bn) say it much more clearly than I do.

====

Wolog we can assume $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.  If $a = ka'$, $b= kb'$ and $gcd(a',b') = 1$ then $a^n - b^n|a^n+b^n \iff k^n(a'^n - b^n)|k^n(a'^n + b'^n) \iff a'^n - b'^n|a'^n + b'^n$.

Wolog we can assume $a > b$.  If $a = b$ we get $0|a^n + b^n$ which only is possible if $a^n + b^n = 0$.

So if $a^n - b^n | a^n + b^n$ then $a^n - b^n|(a^n + b^n)\pm(a^n - b^n)$ and $a^n- b^n|2a^n$ and $a^n-b^n|2b^n$.

So $a^n - b^n|\gcd(2a^n, 2b^n) =2$.  So $a^n - b^n = 1 or 2$.

Let $k = a - b > 0$.  Then $a^n - b^n = (b + k)^n - b^n= \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}b^ik^{n-k} - b^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {n \choose i}b^ik^{n-k}$.  If $n \ge 2$ and $b \ge 1$ then $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {n \choose i}b^ik^{n-k} \ge  {n \choose 1}bk^{n-1} + k^n \ge nb + 1 \ge 3$.

So $a^n - b^n \ge 3$ and $a^n - b^n =1$ or $2$ so we have a contradiction.  This is impossible under the conditions $a,b$ are positive and $n > 1$.

(Several trivial solutions for $n=1$ and $a=2$, $b=1$ or $a$ or $b$ equal zero or $a = -b$ etc. do exist.)

Comment: I got the major part but why $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {n \choose i}b^i \ge {n \choose 1}b + 1 = nb + 1$? I didn't understand where that $1$ came from.

Comment: 'So $a^n - b^n \ge 3$ and $b^n - b^n =1 or 2$ so..' Shouldn't it be So $a^n - b^n \ge 3$ and $a^n - b^n =1 or 2$ so..

Comment: Oops.  I forgot the k terms.  That 1 is $k^n$.

Comment: This may be an interesting aside. Let $m =\gcd(a,b)$. For $n=1$, note that $a-b$ *always* divides $a+b$ iff $\frac{a-b}{m} \in \{1,2\}$, and $a+b$ *never* divides $a+b$ iff $\frac{a-b}{m} \not \in \{1,2\}$. [And to be clear, $a$ and $b$ are *positive* integers.]