# To prove that $(a^n-b^n) \nmid (a^n+b^n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Prove that there are no positive integers $a,b,n>1$ such that $(a^n-b^n)\mid(a^n+b^n)$

**My approach:**

Let $$\frac {(a^n+b^n)}{(a^n-b^n)}=k$$ where, $k$ is a positive integer

$$\therefore k=1+\frac {2b^n}{a^n-b^n}$$

Now, I am unable to prove that $\frac {2b^n}{a^n-b^n}$ is not an integer.

Please help me with my solution or provide a completely new solution.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693235/prove-that-an-bn-does-not-divide-an-bn